# Not getting notifications on drag gestures on screen with MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want just the following touch interactions on my `LineChart` ([MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)):

1. Tap on the chart to select a Highlighted point
2. Drag up or down on the chart, reporting the length of the drag so the program can set new values for `Ymin` and `Ymax` (without changing scale). Basically a "sliding window" on the chart.
3. Similarly with a left or right drag, to move the portion of the X axis that is displayed.

I've created an `OnChartGestureListener` that initially only reacts to `onChartTranslate()`, said to be the drag listener. I see information like that below logged during a drag, but the listener is not being called. Do I have to implement `onChartGestureStart()` and `onChartGestureEnd()` to capture drag information?

```
05-14 14:39:23.011 17319-17319/io.aeroscope.aeroscope I/MPAndroidChart: Drawtime: 3 ms, average: 4 ms, cycles: 477
05-14 14:39:23.031 17319-17319/io.aeroscope.aeroscope I/MPAndroidChart: Drawtime: 7 ms, average: 4 ms, cycles: 478
05-14 14:39:23.050 17319-17319/io.aeroscope.aeroscope I/MPAndroidChart: Drawtime: 5 ms, average: 4 ms, cycles: 479
05-14 14:39:23.086 17319-17319/io.aeroscope.aeroscope I/MPAndroidChart: Drawtime: 4 ms, average: 4 ms, cycles: 480
05-14 14:39:23.133 17319-17319/io.aeroscope.aeroscope I/MPAndroidChart: Drawtime: 4 ms, average: 4 ms, cycles: 481
05-14 14:39:23.174 17319-17319/io.aeroscope.aeroscope I/MPAndroidChart: Drawtime: 4 ms, average: 4 ms, cycles: 482
05-14 14:39:23.216 17319-17319/io.aeroscope.aeroscope I/MPAndroidChart: Drawtime: 5 ms, average: 4 ms, cycles: 483
05-14 14:39:23.256 17319-17319/io.aeroscope.aeroscope I/MPAndroidChart: Drawtime: 4 ms, average: 4 ms, cycles: 484
05-14 14:39:23.298 17319-17319/io.aeroscope.aeroscope I/MPAndroidChart: Drawtime: 5 ms, average: 4 ms, cycles: 485
```

Comment: As I dig into this it appears that a finger drag that is not actually carrying an object with is is considered a "Fling". More as revealed.

Comment: Have you looked at the OnChartGestureListener in the example project? Those logcat messages are just the render time and BTW you are getting a good frame rate so you may not have to optimise further

Comment: Thanks. I noticed in the log that every drag gesture is reported as a Fling, no matter how slowly I move my finger. So the handler I need to call seems to be onChartFling(). Now I have an issue with the sign of the Y-direction movement being reversed; I'm tracking that down. It's unclear from the documentation (that again!) whether onChartTranslate() can be used to report drags when the chart itself isn't being repositioned. I now suspect not.